# Android Studio Generate Signed APK runs OK, but Build APK fails with error (not recognizing certificate)

Tags: android, build, apk, signing

**Generate Signed APK** working correctly, while **Build APK** giving error.

## Observations

1. Our App's JKS Certificate used for Signing was updated recently (to support V2) and was getting used only with **Generate Signed APK**.
2. Development environment stopped working (broke) after usage of new certificate with standard **Build APK** command.
3. It gives following error (basically not recognizing key store)
   Cannot recover key
4. Detail error given by Android Studio is attached below
5. Certificate used was possibly created using Android

**Expected** A certificate recognized by Generate Signed APK should be recognized by normal build as well.

## Error

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to read key sws_ac247 from store "D:\reps\ac247bb\AutoCare247App\app\keystore\ac247_sws_201812.jks": Cannot recover key
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:133)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:110)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt$onEach$1.invoke(_Sequences.kt:1260)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:148)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:108)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:132)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:152)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:633)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(_Sequences.kt:663)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:654)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.transform(BuildElements.kt:140)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.into(BuildElements.kt:115)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElementActionScheduler.into(BuildElementActionScheduler.kt:32)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:393)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor437.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key sws_ac247 from store "D:\reps\ac247bb\AutoCare247App\app\keystore\ac247_sws_201812.jks": Cannot recover key
    at com.android.ide.common.signing.KeystoreHelper.getCertificateInfo(KeystoreHelper.java:212)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackagerBuilder.withSigning(IncrementalPackagerBuilder.java:161)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:646)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:496)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.lambda$doFullTaskAction$2(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:388)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:121)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:391)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:719)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForAllTasks(WaitableExecutor.java:215)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.transform(BuildElements.kt:125)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:328)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:146)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreSpi.java:473)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreDelegator.java:172)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineGetEntry(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(KeyStore.java:1521)
    at com.android.ide.common.signing.KeystoreHelper.getCertificateInfo(KeystoreHelper.java:194)
    ... 63 more
```

Comment: It's not much a solution, but an advice. To build production apks always use command line, or CI. Because these two has to use only gradle, no other internal magic, that can Android studio use.

Comment: What do you mean by "our keystore was updated"? v2 signing shouldn't require the keystore to be "updated". Knowing which operations you performed on the keystore might help debug.

Comment: Hi, how did you manage to solve that?